# GRAILS --- what's the difference between commands grails war and gradle build?

Tags: grails, gradle, build, war

I've heard you should type command

```
 grails war
```

to build your project. I've thought to this point that Gradle is responsible for building the app in Grails. I've been doing the latter with conviction that my app is built. So what's the difference between

```
 grails war
```

and

```
 gradle build
```

?

Is it just that grails war is gradle build + create the war file?

Answer (score 3):

It is not that simple to compare Grails and Gradle. Gradle is a build tool, while Grails is a web application framework.

However, Grails provides a command line tool, that's described in the [docs](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Command%20Line/Usage.html):

> Grails incorporates the powerful build system Gant, which is a Groovy wrapper around Apache Ant.

So, Grails does **not** use Gradle.

The basic usage of the `grails` command looks the following:

```
grails [environment]* [command name]
```

Where especially the *command name* parameter must be one out of predefined values. You can find the documentation on the `war` command [here](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Command%20Line/war.html).

The basic usage of the `gradle` command looks the following:

```
gradle [option...] [task...]
```

The listed task parameters can be names of tasks created either in the `build.gradle` script or by plugins. All mentioned tasks **and** their respective task dependencies will be executed. If you use the [Gradle War Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html), it will generate a `war` task, which will also (transitively) be added as a task dependency of the `build` task. So whenever you call `gradle build`, a WAR file will be created. You can also call this task directly via `gradle war`.

#### EDIT

I just learned that Grails can or even does use Gradle beginning at a certain version. I even found [a list](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/commandLine.html#gradleTasks) on which Grails command calls which Gradle task. According to this list, calling `grails war` is equivalent to calling `gradle assemble`. The `assemble` task directly depends on the `war` task.

Answer (score 1):

`gradle build` is a Gradle lifecycle task which usually consists of other tasks required to build a software like `compileJava` and other lifecycle tasks like `assemble` and `check`.

In case of Grails it delegates build to Gradle and to `war` task and it doesn't include check lifecycle during which unit tests will be executed.